# How to convert a unix-timestamp to formatted date string in firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebasesimplelogin, firebase-hosting

How do I convert a timestamp such as 1333699439 to 2008-07-17T09:24:17?

Currently in firebase, I'm using  - timestamp: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.

Comment: The two answer already tell you how to convert a Unix timestamp to a regular JavaScript date (which you can then display in the user's timezone if needed): `new Date(1333699439*1000)`. But that gives a date of April 6 2012, which is different from the date you have above. Unless you can clarify what you have (code please) and what you want to get out of it, I'm afraid it is not clear what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

the server return the timestamp in seconds So you need to multiple by thousand to get the time stamp in milisec
like

```
var myDate = new Date(timestamp*1000);
var formatedTime=myDate.toJSON();
```

this `formatedTime`  is your required format

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript Date object to do this.

```
var myDate = new Date(timestamp_in_millis*1000);
```

Comment: Christoph - I dont want to use date, but use server timestamp - as the users who are creating accounts may be in different timezones. I don't want to see different timezones and hence wanted to use server timestamp. I need help specific to firebase. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/servervalue/timestamp.html

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If you create your js date object from Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP there is no problem with timezones.